# My Huawei E353 modem is recognized as another model and is not fully functional

Tags: drivers, usb-modem, 3g, huawei

I have `Huawei USB modem E353`. But it is just working with Ubuntu 12.04. I am able to connect to internet.

But I am not able to use `ixconn` and `Gammu` for retrieving messages. I need USSD Functionality. Please advice me on how can i acheive this.

Modem is detected as `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM` which is not my modem.

**dsmeg**

```
[   19.631536] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.631539] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.643278] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.643283] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.643285] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.676131] type=1400 audit(1344863502.640:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=878 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.683977] type=1400 audit(1344863502.648:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/unity-lens-askubuntu/unity-askubuntu-daemon" pid=879 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.689801] type=1400 audit(1344863502.656:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=885 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.690360] type=1400 audit(1344863502.656:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=885 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.692185] type=1400 audit(1344863502.656:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.694865] type=1400 audit(1344863502.660:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.703329] type=1400 audit(1344863502.668:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.756732] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   19.760149] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   19.771338] jme 0000:04:00.5: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[   19.793689] jme 0000:04:00.5: eth0: Link is down
[   19.793904] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.794333] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   19.935396] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   20.665660] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1228) terminated with status 1
[   23.715659] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[   23.917956] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.5
[   23.924254] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.6
[   23.937909] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   23.939217] USB Serial support registered for generic
[   23.955579] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   23.955584] usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
[   23.958098] USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   23.958200] option 2-1.3:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   23.958371] usb 2-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   23.958402] option 2-1.3:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   23.958515] usb 2-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   23.958531] option 2-1.3:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   23.966980] usb 2-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   23.967956] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   23.967959] option: v0.7.2:USB Driver for GSM modems
[   24.924286] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   24.928152] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage       PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   24.929646] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[   24.930323] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[   24.931510] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[   24.932528] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   24.934765] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   48.003006] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[   48.028454] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
[ 2409.681560] show_signal_msg: 39 callbacks suppressed
[ 2409.681569] zenity[4231]: segfault at 32 ip 080551ad sp bf85d2c0 error 4 in zenity[8048000+14000]
[ 2428.536619] zenity[5181]: segfault at 32 ip 080551ad sp bf8cd4e0 error 4 in zenity[8048000+14000]
[ 2448.815826] zenity[6305]: segfault at 32 ip 080551ad sp bfd8ea20 error 4 in zenity[8048000+14000]
[ 2461.042574] zenity[7347]: segfault at 32 ip 080551ad sp bfdda330 error 4 in zenity[8048000+14000]
[ 2506.407263] zenity[8422]: segfault at 32 ip 080551ad sp bfc90060 error 4 in zenity[8048000+14000]
```

[image]

**Commands here** http://pastebin.com/7pBbNNGk

[image]

**AT Commands for E353**

```
[*]H
Manual Rejection of a Network Request for PDP Context Activation (rozłączanie połączenia)

[*]A
Manual Acceptance of a Network Request for PDP Context Activation

[*]D
Mobile Originated Call to a Number (dzwonienie)

[*]S0
Ring before Automatic Answer

[*]S3
Command Line Termination Character

[*]S4
Responds Formatting Character

[*]S5
Editing Character

[*]S6
Pause before Blind Dialling

[*]S7
 Wait for Completion

[*]E
Command Echo Mode
(pl: komenda ta spowoduje wyświetlanei wszystkich oidpowiedzi modemu i naszych zapytań tj. należy wysłać komendę ATE1 aby wyświetlało)

[*]V
Response Format

[*]I
Manufacturer Information about TA

[*]T
Tone Dialling

[*]P
Pulse Dialling

[*]X
CONNECT Result (może być przydatne przy odblokowaniu rozmów)

[*]Z
Reset to Default Configuration

[*]Q
Result Code Suppression

[*]&C
DCD-usage

[*]&D
DTR-usage (może być przydatne przy odblokowaniu rozmów)

[*]&F
Set all TA parameters to factory defined config

[*]+CMGS
Send Message

[*]+CMGW
Message storage

[*]+CMGR
Read a message

[*]+CMGL
Message list

[*]+CMGC
Send command

[*]+CMSS
Send Message from Storage

[*]+CNMA
New Message Acknowledge: AT+CNMA 
Set command confirms correct reception of a new message (SMS-DELIVER or SMS-STATUS-REPORT) which is routed directly to the TE. 

[*]+CSCS
Select TE Character Set

[*]+CMEE
 Report Mobile Equipment error
Set command disables/enables the result code +CME ERROR: <err> as an indication of an error relating to the functionality of the ME

[*]+CREG
Network Registration Info

[*]+CSDH
Show Text Mode Parameters

[*]+CNMI
New message notification setting / New Message Indications to TE

[*]+CGREG
GPRS Network Registration Status / Network registration

[*]+CMMS
More Messages to Send

[*]+CMGF
Set message format / SMS Format

[*]+CGSMS
Select Service for MO SMS Messages / Message bearer domain command

[*]+CSCA
Service Centre Address / SMSC number command

[*]+CSMS
Select Message Service

[*]+CSMP
Set Text Mode Parameters (SMS)

[*]+CPMS
Message storage selection / Preferred Message Storage

[*]+CMGD
Delete Message

[*]+CSCB
Select Cell Broadcast Message Type

[*]^RSTRIGGER
********************------brak------********************

[*]+CLIP
Calling Line Identification Presentation

[*]+CLIR
Calling Line Identification Restriction

[*]+COLP
Connected Line Identification presentation

[*]+CLCC
List Current Calls

[*]+CPAS
Phone Activity Status

[*]+CSTA
Select Type of Address

[*]+CCUG
Closed User Group

[*]+CSSN
Supplementary Service Notification

[*]+CHLD
Call Hold and Multiparty

[*]+CHUP
 Hang Up Call (This command implements the same behave as ATH.)

[*]+VTS
DTMF and Tone Generation

[*]^DTMF
Command for Sending DTMF key value

[*]+CRC
Cellular Result Codes / Command for Setting the Cell Result Codes

[*]+CBST
Select Bearer Service Type / Command for Setting the Bearer Service Type 

[*]+CMOD
Call Mode (może być przydatne przy uaktywnianiu rozmów)

[*]^ALS
********************------brak------********************

[*]+CUUS1
User to User Signalling Service 1 (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]^CDUR
Call Duration Query Command (EM770_AT_ Modem AT Command .pdf)

[*]+CGDCONT
Define PDP Context / PDP environment setting command / Command for Defining the PDP Context

[*]+CGEQNEG
Quality of Service Profile (Negotiated) / Command for Requesting 3G Quality of Service Profile (Negotiated)

[*]+CGDSCONT
Define Secondary PDP Context (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CGEQREQ
 3G Quality of Service Profile (Requested) (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CGEQMIN
3G Quality of Service Profile (Minimum acceptable) (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CGPADDR
Show PDP Address / Show PDP address(es)

[*]+CGCMOD
PDP Context Modify (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CGACT
PDP Context Activate or Deactivate / Command for Activating or Deactivating the PDP Context

[*]+CGANS
Manual Response to a Network Request for PDP Context Activation (CTFPND-3_AT_Command_Reference.pdf) (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CGTFT
Traffic Flow Template Read Dynamic Parameters (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]^CGDNS
********************------brak------********************

[*]+CGAUTO
Automatic Response to a Network Request for PDP Context Activation

[*]+CGDATA
Enter Data State

[*]^TRIG
********************------brak------********************

[*]^GCFIND
********************------brak------********************

[*]+CGATT
PS attach or detach / Command for Attaching the MT to or Detaching the MT from the GPRS Service

[*]^CGCATT
********************------brak------********************

[*]+COPS
Operator Selection / PLMN selection / Command for Selecting Operators

[*]+CGCLASS
GPRS Mobile Station Class (tryby PS / CS)

[*]AT+CFUN?
Set Phone Functionality / Command for Setting the Work Mode

[*]+CGMI
Request Manufacturer Identification / Manufacturer information query command / Command for Querying the Vendor Information 

[*]+CGMM
Request Model Identification / Product model ID command / Command for Querying the Product Mode

[*]+GMM
TA Model Identification / Querying the Product Model Number Request

[*]+CGMR
 Request Revision Identification / Software version number query command / Command for Querying the Software Version Number 

[*]+CGSN
Request Product Serial Number Identification / IMEI query command

[*]+GSN
Request TA serial Number / IMEI query command

[*]+CIMI
Request International Mobile Subscriber Identity / IMSI query command

[*]+CSQ
Signal Quality / RSSI query function command

[*]^CBND
"AT^CBND?" zwraca aktualne ustawienie "Band" modemu z komendy "AT^SYSCFG"

[*]^CPDW
********************------brak------********************
Może ma cos wspólnego z CPWD (g20software.pdf g20 AT Commands.book)

[*]^HWVER
Command for Querying hardware version number / Hardware version number query function

[*]^HVER
Hardware version number query function (takie smao jak ^HWVER)

[*]^FHVER
Zwraca: "Model modemu wersję firmware, wersję hardware" np. "E353s-2A 21.157.06.00.264,CH2E353SM Ver.A"

[*]^PFVER
Zwraca ciąg znaków V3R i "Compile date / time"

[*]+CLAC
List All Available AT Commands

[*]^SN
Zwraca Serial number (numer seryjny urządzenia)

[*]+GCAP
Request Overall Capabilities for TA / The Complete Capabilities List command (+GCAP) should indicate the major capability areas of the TA (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]^SRVST
Command for Indicating service state change / Service state change indication

[*]^MODE
System mode change event indication / Command for Indicating system mode change event (coś nie chce działać, moze być przydatne do podtrzyumania HSPA+)

[*]^SIMST
SIM state change indication (coś nie chce działać, moze być przydatne do rozpoznawania braku PS w modemie i karcie Aero2)

[*]^HS
TE-MS handshake function command / Command for Handshaking between MS and TE

[*]+CPLS
Selection of preferred PLMN list (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CPOL
Preferred Operator List / Preferred PLMN list

[*]+CPBS
Phonebook memory selection / Command for Selecting the Phone Book Memory

[*]^CPBR
Phonebook reading / Command for Reading the Phone Book

[*]+CPBR
Read phonebook entries / Checking the Parameter Range Supported by the +CPBR Command (HUAWEI_MU509_HSDPA_LGA_Module_AT_Command_Interface_Specification-(V100R001_01,English).pdf)

[*]^CPBW
Command for Writing the Phone Book / Phonebook writing

[*]+CPBW
Write phonebook entry / Write Phonebook Entries

[*]^SCPBW
Write Phonebook (LC6341 AT Command Set User Manual 201154154055464.pdf)

[*]^SCPBR
Read Phonebook (LC6341 AT Command Set User Manual 201154154055464.pdf)

[*]+CNUM
Subscriber Number

[*]+CPBF
Find Phonebook Entries / Command for Querying phonebook Query

[*]+CSIM
 Generic SIM access (27007-a50.pdf)

[*]+CPIN
Enter PIN / PIN management command

[*]^ICCID
"AT^ICCID?" return integrated circuit card identification from the SIM card (RIM_1802G_RIM_1902G_AT_Commands_Guide.pdf)

[*]^CPIN
PIN management command ^CPIN (new feature) / Command for Manage PIN (indicate remaining password input times)

[*]+CRSM
Command for Accessing a SIM Card Through Restricted SIM Access / Restricted SIM access

[*]^PNN
EFPNN (PLMN Network Name) - contains the full and short form version of the network name 
 for the registered PLMN. 
 If the Operator Name Source is CPHS Operator Name String long and short form, 
 refer to <indValue>, the following two SIM Elementary Files are used: 
 EFONString (Operator Name String) - contains the name of the PLMN operator who issued the 
 SIM. 
 EFOPShort (Operator Name Short form) - contains a short form of the name of the PLMN 
 operator who issued the SIM. 
(s000453c.pdf)
********************------brak------********************

[*]^CPNN
********************------brak------********************

[*]^OPL
EFOPL (Operator PLMN List) - contains the PLMN identification and location ID together with 
 the index of the corresponding PNN record. 
********************------brak------********************

[*]^CARDLOCK
Card lock command / AT^CARDLOCK is used for unlock the datacard. When the SIM card which is not allowed by the 
operator (Called illegal SIM card) is inserted into the datacard, the datacard can detect it is a illegal 
SIM card and require a unlock code before it can register the network. If the right  unlock code is 
inputted,  the  datacard  is unlocked  and  then  any  other  opertator’s  SIM  card  can  work  in  this 
datacard. If the wrong unlock code inputted exceeds 10 times, the datacard is locked forever and 
only  the  SIM card which  is  allowed  by  the  operator  (Called  legal  SIM card) can work with this 
datacard. 

[*]+CCWA
Call Waiting / Command for Reporting of call waiting

[*]+CCFC
Call Forwarding Number and Conditions / Call Forwarding Command

[*]+CUSD
Unstructured Supplementary Service / USSD command

[*]^CMLCK
"AT^CMLCK=?" zwraca: "^CMLCK: ("PS")"
********************------brak------********************

[*]+CLCK
Facility Lock / PIN enabling and query function

[*]+CPWD
Change Password / PIN password modifying

[*]^CDSF
********************------brak------********************

[*]^CDCF
********************------brak------********************

[*]^CDQF
********************------brak------********************

[*]^DSFLOWCLR
DS traffic reset

[*]^DSFLOWQRY
DS traffic query

[*]^DSFLOWRPT
DS traffic reporting

[*]^CPAM
Central Processor Auxiliary Magazine :))) / Control Plane Assurance Magazine :)))
********************------brak------********************

[*]^TIME
********************------brak------********************

[*]+CTZR
Time Zone Reporting

[*]^STSF
SIM ToolKit Set Facilities (TF_PIML PLUS_AT_Commands_Interface_Guide1.pdf)

[*]^STGI
COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
SIM ToolKit Get Information (TF_PIML PLUS_AT_Commands_Interface_Guide1.pdf)

[*]^STGR
SIM ToolKit Give Response (TF_PIML PLUS_AT_Commands_Interface_Guide1.pdf)

[*]^IMSICHG
COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
********************------brak------********************

[*]^PDPSTUB
********************------brak------********************

[*]^CWAS
********************------brak------********************

[*]^CGAS
********************------brak------******************

[*]^MFREELOCKSIZE
"AT^MFREELOCKSIZE?" zwraca: "^MFREELOCKSIZE:liczba"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CPULOAD
"AT^CPULOAD?" zwraca: "^CPULOAD:0 OK"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CELLINFO
********************------brak------******************

[*]^MEANRPT
zwraca 0
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CCC
********************------brak------******************

[*]^SPN
Return (U)SIM card's  / Service Provider Name / Command for Getting service provider name

[*]^CARDMODE
Unsolicited Result Code Control (201154154055464.pdf)

[*]^CURC
Unsolicited report control command / Command for Controlling unsolicited report

[*]^CMSR
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CMGI
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CMMT
********************------brak------******************

[*]^AUTHDATA
********************------brak------******************

[*]^DHCP
(można sprawdzać po połączeniu)
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CRPN
********************------brak------******************

[*]^GLASTERR
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NDISDUP
(łączy modem w trybie NDIS)
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NDISCONN
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NDISSTATQRY
(wyświetla informacje o połączneiu NDIS)
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NDISADD
"AT^NDISADD=?" zwraca: "^NDISADD: (0-1),(IP_Address),(Primary_DNS),(Secondary_DNS),(Primary_NBNS),(Secondary_NBNS)"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^DNSP
"AT^DNSP=?" zwraca "^DNSP: (-PrimaryDNS-)"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^DNSS
"AT^DNSS" zwraca "^DNSS: (-SecondaryDNS-)"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^DLOADVER
Zwraca wersję bootyloadera (oem sbl) w Download mode?
********************------brak------******************

[*]^DLOADINFO
Interesująca funkcja. Zwraca takze wartość ^MODE np.:

"AT^DLOADINFO?

swver:21.157.06.00.264

isover:UTPS21.005.11.10.264_MAC21.005.11.08.264


webuiver:

product name:E353s-2A

dload type:0

OK

^MODE: 5,9"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NVBACKUP
All Backs up items stored in non-volatile memory
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NVRESTORE
zapewne przywraca backup
********************------brak------******************

[*]^AUTHORITYVER
zwraca wersję ?czegoś? (IMEI?)
"AT^AUTHORITYVER?
1000
OK"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^AUTHORITYID
Zwraca imei i drguą liczbę po precinku:
"AT^AUTHORITYID?
IMEI,0
OK"
********************------brak------******************

[*]^GODLOAD
Przełącza w tryb Download Mode (oem sbl) bądź bootloadera.
********************------brak------******************

[*]AT^RESET
Resetuje modem, uruchamia ponownie możliwe, że do ustawień fabrycznych.
********************------brak------******************

[*]^NVRSTSTTS
********************------brak------******************

[*]^HWNATQRY
"AT^HWNATQRY?" zwraca liczbę
********************------brak------******************

[*]^FLASHINFO
Zwraca jakieś adresy w pamięci?
********************------brak------******************

[*]^COMM
********************------brak------******************

[*]^HSPA
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CSNR

"AT^CSNR?" zwraca dwie liczby, analzia pochodzi z: http://knol.google.com/k/modem-based-3g-signal-analysis#
Range (SNR-A),(SNR-B): (-145--60),(-32-0)

    In response to the CSNR command, the modem responds with two numbers. Due to not knowing exactly how these numbers are measured and calculated (see Modem specifics), they have been termed SNR-A and SNR-B.
    (-145--60) means that
        SNR-A response from the modem will be a number from -145 to -60
    (-32-0) means that:
        SNR-B response from the modem will be a number from -32 to 0
    SNR-A ⇀SNR-A value returned from the modem

    Note that, unlike in the RSSI case, we defer explaining the meaning of SNR-A for later, subject to further investigation. This due to not knowing what the modem is exactly measuring in this case.

SNR-B ⇀ SNR-B value returned from the modem

    Note that, unlike in the RSSI case, we defer explaining the meaning of SNR-B for later, subject to further investigation. This is due to not knowing what the modem is exactly measuring in this case.
********************------brak------******************

[*]^FREQLOCK
(kanały do blokownaia na modemie?)
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CFPLMN
"AT^CFPLMN?" wyswietla listę operatorów do których się nie zalogoaliśmy?
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CQST
przyjmuje dwie wartości, 1 i 0
********************------brak------******************

[*]^CAATT
przyjmuje dwie wartości, 1 i 0
********************------brak------******************

[*]^SYSINFO
zwraca sporo informacji, wyjasnienai są dostępne

[*]^SYSCFG
ustawienia, częstotliwości, trybu sieci etc.

[*]^RXDIV


[*]^PCSCINFO

[*]^CELLSRCH

[*]+CLVL

[*]^VMSET

[*]^CDTMFS

[*]^CDTMFE

[*]+GMI

[*]+GMR

[*]^SETPORT

[*]^VERTIME

[*]^APHPLMN

[*]^ANQUERY

[*]^APPWRONREG

[*]^APTHROUGHPUT

[*]^APCONNST

[*]^WIFIGLOBALMAC

[*]^SCID

[*]+CSQLVL

[*]^CSQLVLEXT

[*]^APPDMVER

[*]^AUTHVER

[*]^IPV6CAP

[*]^DHCPV6

[*]^APRAINFO

[*]^APLANADDR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit [How to Install Huawei Mobile Partner 21 in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323396/how-to-install-mobile-partner-21-for-ubuntu)

NO need of confusing WAMMU or other things, If there comes any problem, contact me. I also followed that guide and got everything working except voice calling. My modem is E303U and mobile partner supports almost every  Huawei modem.

For windows, mobile partner 23 is available. But for ubuntu, this is very old.( 2011)

Install drivers from automounted drive itself.

You also need to run it as root, otherwise mobile partner will not detect signal.