# How to Install Huawei Mobile Partner 21 in Ubuntu

Tags: mobile-broadband, huawei

We can't send SMSs, USSD codes, make calls or get Data Usage from Huawaei 3G dongles/data cards without Huawei mobile partner. How do we install it?

Answer (score 11):

### Installing Mobile Partner 21 [Customized Version]

Mobile Partner is the most popular program, but it version 23 is not available for Linux, you can install version 21 following the steps below

First, you want to download

32bit - http://www.mediafire.com/download/9oa5g9dx5xeoy97/mp21.zip
64bit - http://ubuntuone.com/3w67SSZzET4ZdyJSfG51za

**How to Install**

- You need login as root:

  ```
  sudo -i
  ```
- Go to the directory you downloaded the file to using `cd`, for example

  ```
  cd /home/hasiya/Desktop
  ```
- Unzip

  ```
  unzip mp21.zip
  ```
- Go into mp21 folder

  ```
  cd mp21
  ```
- Install MobilePartner by using the `install` script

  ```
  ./install
  ```

[image]

4. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.
5. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct
6. Finish installing

### How to run

- Run MobilePartner in your install path
  eg: # //MobilePartner
- Plug in your device, it will run automatically (Not supported in Xandros)

You have installed Mobile Partner to your Ubuntu machine, final result :

[image]

Comment: I have followed your answer, and it is the most forward way to install Mobile Partner, however, I would advise against it. It is full of bugs and compromises the security of your system. The most important one is that it adds `ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` to your `sudoers` file which allows to run all sudo commands without password!

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more... It's a security threat.

Comment: I tried installing MobilePartner (Tata Photon Plus) but I couldn't. Will I be able to use Photon Plus with the above said MobilePartner?

Comment: The above method does not work for Ubuntu 12.04, Linux Mint Cinnamon!

Comment: Dude!! You made my day... :-) And this [link](http://tryitnw.blogspot.in/2012/02/huawei-mobile-broadband-dongle-not.html) also helpful..

Comment: pleaase update the 64bit url

Comment: Please update the 64 bit url link.. as the ubuntu one has been disconnected.

Comment: @GerhardBurger@Naveen So how do I revert the changes made my the installer once I've installed it?

Comment: But there is no option to provide DNS

Comment: 64 bit Link is down

Comment: 64 bit Link update is needed

Comment: Don't know why does it need to add the line `ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` to the `sudoers` file. I needed to manually edit that file afterwards to make `sudo` command accept password.