# Huawei USB Modem E303 not working after installing JAVA

Tags: huawei

**Huawei USB Modem E303 not working** after installing JAVA... i installed Xtreme Download Manger and ubuntu installed java... after that modem isn't detected.Tried reinstalling

> usb-modeswitch

, but it didn't work

Here’s what dmesg says

```
[ 2824.231057] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2824.247948] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14fe
[ 2824.247956] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 2824.247962] usb 3-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[ 2824.247968] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[ 2824.300718] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2824.300827] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 2824.300946] usb-storage 3-2:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2824.301022] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-2:1.1
[ 2824.301115] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 2825.300336] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2825.300370] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2825.302688] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[ 2825.302959] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 2825.304495] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[ 2825.310547] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 2825.311925] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2825.451576] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[ 2825.459956] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[ 3688.963776] systemd-hostnamed[6133]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Comment: Explain what specifically doesn't work and provide some output and what you've tried to fix it yourself.

Comment: edited my post on above.please be kind enough to give me a quick response because i'm not a hardcore linux user

Comment: how can I find the connection name...?? this is the terminal result `Satellite-L50-A:~$ nmcli nm wwan on && nmcli con up id 'Dialog GSM e Prepaid (Kitbb)'
Error: Unknown connection: Dialog GSM Prepaid (Kitbb)`

Comment: Open the Network Connection application. There will be your connection names. Above one is just an example.

Comment: visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/323396/how-to-install-mobile-partner-21-for-ubuntu , this will solve almost all your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unlocked modems are working with Ubuntu. If you want to unlock:

1. Download [Universal master code program](http://huaweifirmwares.com/download/universal-master-code-calculator-download/),type in your modem `IMEI number` and calculate it. Now you have generate codes, which you need write down.
2. Now download your modem firmware from [huawei](http://huaweifirmwares.com) web site, then launch it. After a few minutes it'll ask for an unlock code, that you generated earlier in step 1. Now type it in and it will unlocked your modem, which then will work with/under Ubuntu.