# USSD fails due to Missing interface org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Modem3gpp.Ussd in 14.04

Tags: dbus, modem-manager, ussd

after upgrade to 14.04 every time i use USSD i get a dbus-send error due to missing interface in the object path

```
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
```

Dose any one know how i can add this missing interface

```
root@JATIVA:~# dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ModemManager1 /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Modem3gpp.Ussd.Initiate string:*888#
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Modem3gpp.Ussd' on object at path /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
```

[image: d-feet screenshot of object path]

Comment: Does it work if you boot the 14.04 live usb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modem Manger / GUI is not expected to work for all 3G dongles out there. You might want to use the software developed by the manufacturer of your dongle to use the USSD feature.

For Huawei dongles:

### Huawei Mobile Partner

[image]

There is a higher chance that you can find the Huawei Mobile Partner available inside your dongle.

If you don't have the it with you, heres how to download and install it:

### Installing Huawei Mobile Partner 22

- If you don't have Internet to the host machine, first [click here & download the Huawei Mobile Partner 22](https://db.tt/XtrP9KPw) to your Home directory. Then execute the below command in Terminal:

  ```
   tar -xvzf megafone.tar.gz
   cd mp22-linux-64
   chmod +x install
   sudo ./install
  ```
- If you already have Internet to your machine copy the below command into the Terminal at once and execute it:

  ```
  wget -O mp22-linux-64.tar.gz https://db.tt/XtrP9KPw
  tar -xvzf mp22-linux-64.tar.gz
  cd mp22-linux-64
  chmod +x install
  sudo ./install
  ```

If your dongle is not detected by 22nd version of mobile partner, you may try installing [21](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323396/how-to-install-huawei-mobile-partner-21-in-ubuntu) or [23](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29344756/LinuxStuff/mp23.tar.gz).

---

If you have a Prolink or ZTE dongle see ZTE mobile connect section from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424669/how-to-get-my-3g-zte-mf-xxx-prolink-phs-xxx-dongle-working-in-linux#answer-424670).