# Modem broadband issue

Tags: 14.04

I have Mobile broadband modem works fine on windows, on Ubuntu 14.04 when I plugged it first time it works fine but after 10 minuets it disconnected and it doesn't reconnect till I make restart for Ubuntu.

Comment: Open-up your Ubuntu software center, search for `usb-modeswitch` is installed. That usually needs. Also, can you please elaborate what happens when you try to reconnect?? or you mean that it doesn't appear on the network panel?

Comment: no it's appeared but I can't reconnect till restart, it just give me disconnected banner.

Comment: usb-modeswitch is installed with the last version

Answer (score 0):

Usually such a device gets disconnected due to poor signals. See if it's heating.

Sometimes you need to install proprietary drivers for the dongal to make it properly functional

See :

- [How to get my 3G ZTE MF XXX / Prolink PHS XXX dongle working in Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424669/how-to-get-my-3g-zte-mf-xxx-prolink-phs-xxx-dongle-working-in-linux)
- [How to Install Huawei Mobile Partner 21 in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323396/how-to-install-mobile-partner-21-for-ubuntu) (For Huawei dongals)