# Problem with connecting mobile broadband in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, bug-reporting, mobile-broadband

When I plugged mobile broadband top right bar `new mobile broadband` option appears then immediately disappears then again appears then immediately disappears and so on...

If I click on `new mobile broadband` immediately then it gives error when applying settings because modem disconnect before I configure it. I have idea net-setter (similar to mobile partner of huawei)

[image]

On Ubuntu 14.04 I can't connect by using it because of above mentioned problem.(**Unstable detection of mobile-broadband**)

Wired connection (USB tethering from android) is working fine.

Thus, How can I Solve It?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that works for me:

- First stop modemmanager by `sudo stop modemmanager`.
- Then plug net-setter & wait for 20-30 seconds.
- Then start modemmanager by `sudo start modemmanager`

Now when modem (net-setter) detected ; it is stable hence, after connecting, I get stable connection until disconnect or unplugged!

But it is not permanent solution as I have to follow above method each time to get stable connection. So, any other solution will be appreciated.

Note that : Directly restart modemmanager by `sudo restart modemmanager` not helpful for me.

**Additional info**: Actually there is no need to start/stop service `network-manager` entirely. Only go for **`modemmanager`**.

Comment: Initially I dont have modemmanager, so I installed apt-get install modemmanager

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and works for me.

1. Go edit connection and add mobile broadband > choose connection type.
2. After setting up you mobile broadband the problem is the option disappears or your mobile broadband device is not detected.
3. Go to your files and on devices unmount your usb mobile broadband.
4. Then enable networking.
5. By this time options appears and click enable mobile broadband.

Think when you inserted the usb mobile broadband the system consider it as storage device hence not detected and when I unmounted it was detected.