# Ubuntu 14.04 and Huawei E173s - only storage mode

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-modem, huawei

I've tried for several hours to configure Huawei E173s on Ubuntu 14.04. Only what I get is that Ubuntu sees stick as storage(CD or microUSB) but I'm not able to force it to work as modem(to connect to internet). I've installed drivers which were inside device, also tried with other drivers. Device for sure isn't damaged because on Windows it works. Can you help me find how can I solve this issue?
Some information about device:
lsusb :(it shows modem switched off)

> Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1c05 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173s
>   3G broadband stick (modem on)

modem-manager-gui: does not see any device

dmesg(after plug-in device):

> [ 2116.820086] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using
>   ehci-pci 
> [ 2117.191617] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1,
>   idProduct=1c0b 
> [ 2117.191621] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2,
>   Product=1, SerialNumber=0 
> [ 2117.191624] usb 2-1: Product: HUAWEI
>   Mobile 
> [ 2117.191626] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI 
> [ 2117.193618]
>   usbserial_generic 2-1:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for
>   testing and one-off prototypes. 
> [ 2117.193628] usbserial_generic
>   2-1:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper
>   driver. 
> [ 2117.193635] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.0: generic converter
>   detected 
> [ 2117.193815] usb 2-1: generic converter now attached to
>   ttyUSB0 
> [ 2117.193994] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: The "generic"
>   usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes. 
> [
>   2117.194001] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver. 
> [ 2117.194008]
>   usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: generic converter detected 
> [ 2117.194165]
>   usb 2-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB1 
> [ 2121.020542]
>   generic ttyUSB0: generic converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 
> [
>   2121.020559] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.0: device disconnected 
> [ 2121.024451] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 5 
> [ 2121.030294] generic ttyUSB1: generic converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1 
> [
>   2121.030311] usbserial_generic 2-1:1.1: device disconnected 
> [ 2128.476089] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci 
> [ 2129.020787] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1,
>   idProduct=1c05 
> [ 2129.020799] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2,
>   Product=1, SerialNumber=0 [ 2129.020807] usb 2-1: Product: HUAWEI
>   Mobile 
> [ 2129.020813] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI 
> [ 2129.023032]
>   option 2-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
> [ 2129.023429]
>   usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0 
> [
>   2129.023652] option 2-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected [ 2129.023857] usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1 
> [ 2129.024097] option 2-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter
>   detected [ 2129.024288] usb 2-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now
>   attached to ttyUSB2 
> [ 2129.024468] usb-storage 2-1:1.3: USB Mass
>   Storage device detected 
> [ 2129.024865] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1:1.3 
> [
>   2129.025199] usb-storage 2-1:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected 
> [ 2129.025336] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1:1.4 
> [ 2130.025148] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 [
>   2130.025258] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 
> [ 2130.027326] sr1: scsi-1 drive 
> [ 2130.027461] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
> [ 2130.027665] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached
>   scsi generic sg2 type 5 
> [ 2130.028217] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi
>   generic sg3 type 0 
> [ 2130.033255] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI
>   removable disk

ls /dev/tty* (as you can see heres missing any ttyUSB*)

> /dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10 
>   /dev/ttyS26 /dev/tty0   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty55
>   /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS27 /dev/tty1   /dev/tty25  /dev/tty40 
>   /dev/tty56      /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS28 /dev/tty10  /dev/tty26 
>   /dev/tty41  /dev/tty57      /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS29 /dev/tty11 
>   /dev/tty27  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty58      /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS3
>   /dev/tty12  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty59      /dev/ttyS15 
>   /dev/ttyS30 /dev/tty13  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty6
>   /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS31 /dev/tty14  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty45 
>   /dev/tty60      /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS4 /dev/tty15  /dev/tty30 
>   /dev/tty46  /dev/tty61      /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS5 /dev/tty16 
>   /dev/tty31  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty62      /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS6
>   /dev/tty17  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty63      /dev/ttyS2
>   /dev/ttyS7 /dev/tty18  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty7
>   /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS8 /dev/tty19  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty8 
>   /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS9 /dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9 
>   /dev/ttyS22 /dev/tty20  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty51  /dev/ttyprintk 
>   /dev/ttyS23 /dev/tty21  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty52  /dev/ttyS0
>   /dev/ttyS24 /dev/tty22  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty53  /dev/ttyS1
>   /dev/ttyS25

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/468691/37165) has asked on "USB mobile broadband dongles in Ubuntu (14.04)? Where to start?" and has an upvoted answer. Start from there.

Comment: As I've written my modem is detected as device but it does not want to switch to modem-mode. I've tried everything in this tutorial and this does not help. Maybe some logs can help you detect where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to sakis3g tool:) + umtskeeper: http://mintakaconciencia.net/squares/umtskeeper/