# huawei modem cannot be used to connect to internet

Tags: usb-modem

This is what I got after running `lsusb`:

```
 bundala@bundala-Lenovo-G40-30:~$ lsusb
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 001 Device 006: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
 Bus 001 Device 008: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I use the modem to connect to the internet?

Comment: Actually your modem is detected. See the sixth entry.

Comment: but it does not appear in the  network list

Comment: Check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/419659/mobile-broadband-stick-sometimes-not-detected-at-all

Comment: This should clear some of your querries.

Comment: This might also help:http://askubuntu.com/questions/424669/how-to-get-my-3g-zte-mf-xxx-prolink-phs-xxx-dongle-working-in-linux#answer-424670

Comment: Which modem are you using?

Comment: I am using Huawei E173u-1.sorry for late reply

Comment: @PaschalBundala Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/866425/edit) your question with modem details and os version.  And Did you try answers in link provided by Manish Kumar Bisht?