# how to i connect huawei dongle to my ubuntu 12.4 version?

Tags: huawei

i have purchased HP pavilion laptop.Then i bought HUAWEI vodafone dongle and connect to my laptop it would not connected to my laptop.i had installed Ubuntu 12.4 version.How to i will connect this dongle to my laptop?

Comment: What do you mean it would not connect?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally once you insert your dongle; in the Network Manager Application Indicator list (on the top bar of your screen), you should now have an option something like "Create new CDMA connection". Click that and the setup wizard should open.

Answer (score 1):

Press Network Button in Unity panel

Press Last Edit Option > Press Add Button > Select Mobile Broadband Press create

Then select County, Providers and Plan.

**Method 2**

You can install Mobile partner software for Linux [Download Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/7a0aa7414cud40h/E620_LMT_internet_Linux.zip)

[Installation instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323396/how-to-install-mobile-partner-21-for-ubuntu) is here in the answer of question