# how to make USSD call from huawei data card E1731

Tags: usb-modem, tty, huawei, gammu, ussd

I have huwai data card e1731 using as dongle on ubuntu 14.04.

Now i want to make ussd calls from data card.

here are few lines of 'dmesg'

```
 usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   23.059584] option 1-1.1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   23.059757] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   23.059806] option 1-1.1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   23.059876] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   23.059892] option 1-1.1:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   23.059957] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   23.068923] cdc_ether 1-1.1:1.1 wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 02:50:f3:00:00:00
[   23.068951] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   24.049305] scsi 14:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   24.049812] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
```

I tried gammu :

```
sudo gammu getussd *123#
Error opening device, it doesn't exist.
```

my gammurc

```
   device = /dev/ttyUSB0
   connection = mbus
```

replaced ttyUSB0 with ttyUSB1 and tty USB2 but same result

i tried gsm-ussd

```
sudo gsm-ussd -m /dev/ttyUSB0
Can't get lockfile /var/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0 - probably already in use!
```

Same results with other two USB1 and USB2

i tried prepaid-manager-applet with setup of vendors and country.

```
We can't find the information on how to query the account balance from your provider 'Airtel' in our database.
```

waiting for your any help..

Comment: this worked for me [Huawei modem voice call](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464661/way-to-call-through-huawei-modem-in-14-04-e303/950301#950301)

Answer (score 1):

While using gammu to send ussd the device must not be connected to internet.
Use the command `gammu-detect -> .gammurc` to automatically generate the config file in your home directory. Open the hidden config file and check for detected devices like gammu, gammu1, gammu2 etc.
Send ussd by issuing commands in terminal like `sudo gammu getussd *123#` , `sudo gammu 1 getussd *123#` , `sudo gammu 2 getussd *123#` etc to change between different devices.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install **modem manager GUI** from ubuntu software center.

It sends & receives USSD call,SMS,scan for operators,traffic,provides information of signal strentgh,contacts.

modem manager GUI is a graphical interface of modem manager.So you have to connect the modem through modem manager which is default in ubuntu.