# Huawei E303C 3G modem device - Mobile partner unable to start(no GUI), calling, USSD issue

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, 3g

I have installed the NDIS drivers needed successfully and got connected too using wvdial and Ubuntu's network manager, the device is detected every time whenever plugged in.

The problem i faced is i can't make a call or receive a call, for doing so i need a mobile partner that i can see in driver installation directory, i am not able to start it. how to register the autorun settings into the current system? i am stuck here help me out. at the end, i am not able to run mobile partner or can't see any GUI running for it !? guide me to get it working!

Kindly note i am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus) and the device Huawei E303C is detected and recognized by the system and i am able to connect to the internet but I want to make a call using Mobile Partner, USSD checks and other functions i can't use.

Thanks again.

their are other file called runhwactivator, HWActivator, skeleton, Uninstall, HWActivator, startmobilepartner & readme file for linux installation.

what i did next is, have a look at snapshots attached

[readme file and terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy8rf.png)
[terminal output for other execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGouv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use a huawei K3772 modem and this is how i was able to make a USSD to check balance and also make a call in ubuntu.**modem-manager-gui** and **mmcli** didnt work for my modem

I use AT commands.It is usually a foolproof method to check ussd, send and retrieve sms and also make calls.

**Checking USSD**

ALT1----using modem-manager-gui:

```
sudo apt install modem-manager-gui
```

*ALT1 does not work for some modems*

ALT2----Using AT commands (works for all modems)

To send AT commands in linux i prefer picocom (others are putty, minicom, screen):

```
sudo apt install picocom
```

insert your dongle into pc and should be detected by Network manager applet

Find out the various ports of the modem:

```
ls /dev/ttyU*
```

*usually the dialogue port is /dev/ttyUSB0. We would "talk" to the modem on this port*

start picocom on that port:

```
sudo picocom -c /dev/ttyUSB0
```

*the -c means local echo on, so that you can see the AT commands as you type*

check USSD with:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*124#"
```

This should give you a reply such as **"Your balance is ..."**

*Tip:- Some modems do not give this human readable reply but instead give something like "0933737ADRE35338..." which is hex*

To fix such a problem your modems char set has to be set to GSM

check the current character set mode:

```
AT+CSCS?
```

check available modes:

```
AT+CSCS=?
```

To use plain-text USSD, modem must be in GSM

```
AT+CSCS="GSM"
```

Now check ussd:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*124#"
```

for subsequent replies where you have to give a reply to the network
for instance after checking ussd you get a reply like **1.Top up 2.check wallet**

to choose **Top up** do:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"1"
```

To quit the session do:
`ctrl+a` followed by `ctrl+x`

To make a voice call on huawei modem on ubuntu linux go here [Huawei make voice call on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464661/way-to-call-through-huawei-modem-in-14-04-e303/950301#950301)